# Adding JWT Bearer Auth to OpenAPI3 NSwag generated Client

Tags: swagger, authorization, openapi, blazor-webassembly, nswag

I have a Blazor WebAssm app that I want to secure with basic JWT bearer tokens, its an internally used app, so the actual authentication will be via a check against internal AD.  My WebAPI layer is using the built in Swagger to generate an OpenAPI 3 document, which my client then uses to create a C# class for using it.

So I have the OpenAPI client and can call it from my blazor app, but I can't work out how to add security to either the API side or the Blazor side.

I'm using .NET 5 on both the WebAPI layer and the Blazor client.

Answer (score 4):

This took way to long to figure out, and I'm sure there are better ways. But here are the steps I did to add this:

Firstly in the WebAPI Startup, you need to configure Swagger properly:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "My Cool Tool",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "My Cool API",
            });

            //add jwt authentication definition to the OpenAPI doc.
            var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Name = "JWT Authentication",
                Description = "Enter JWT Bearer Token Only",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                Scheme = "bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                }
            };

            c.AddSecurityDefinition(securityScheme.Reference.Id, securityScheme);

            //to indicate the entire API is secured, add this.  NOTE it does NOT secure it, just indicates it is.
            //c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            //{ 
            //    {securityScheme, new string[]{ } }
            //});

            //this filter does add if an API is secured based upon the Authorize attribute
            c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();                
        });
```

Note the last few lines are key, the `AddSecurityDefinition` puts a chunk at the end detailing the scheme your using.  If you uncomment those lines then the security scheme is added to every operation (unlikely what you want!), so the last line just adds it to those operations/methods with the `[Authorize]` tag.

And that `SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter` is as follows

```
public class SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        //if the controller method has the authorize attribute, get the roles
        var requiredRoles = context.MethodInfo
            .GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
            .Select(attr => attr.Roles)
            .Distinct();

        if (requiredRoles.Any())
        {
            //add the fact that this operation could return the 401/403 HTTP status codes
            operation.Responses.Add("401", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Unauthorized" });
            operation.Responses.Add("403", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Forbidden" });

            //add the fact that this operation is secured by bearer auth
            var bearerScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                }
            };

            operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    { bearerScheme, requiredRoles.ToList() }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

You can skip the roles part and just replace the `ToList` with an empty string array.

Finally we've got some more standard authorisation setup to do in Startup:

```
        //get token management settings
        var token = Configuration.GetSection("tokenManagement").Get<TokenManagement>();
        services.AddSingleton(token);

        //add authentication
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = token.Issuer,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(token.Secret)),
                ValidAudience = token.Audience,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
        //add the authentication user service
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
```

`TokenManagement` is a poco storing some of the config items for the tokens.
`UserService` is the class where you have `IsValidUser` which is where you add your actual check.

Finally you need some kinda of login method:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("login")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(LoginResult), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public ActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginRequest request)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid Request");
        }

        if (!_userService.IsValidUser(request.UserName, request.Password))
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid Request");
        }

        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, request.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, _userService.GetUserRole(request.UserName))
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_tokenManagement.Secret));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
            _tokenManagement.Issuer,
            _tokenManagement.Audience,
            claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_tokenManagement.AccessExpiration),
            signingCredentials: credentials);

        var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtToken);

        _logger.LogInformation($"User [{request.UserName}] logged in the system.");

        return Ok(new LoginResult
        {
            UserName = request.UserName,
            JwtToken = token
        });
    }
```

At this point you can decorate your api methods with the `[Authorize]` attribute and subsequent calls should be blocked without the Bearer header in the request.

For the client side, NSwag will generate a `partial` class for the client, which is where I expanded it and provided a body to one of the provided `PrepareRequest` methods, as this is called just before the `HttpClient` does the `Send`.

```
    partial void PrepareRequest(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage request, string url)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Prepare Request: {request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri}");
        var user = _storage.GetItem<LoginResult>("user");

        if (user != null)
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", user.JwtToken);
            
            _logger.LogDebug($"Headers: {request.Headers.ToString()}");
        }
    }
```

The key thing here is that this method has to be synchronous as the generated client doesn't `await` it.
So in my case I used the `Blazored.LocalStorage` package to get those sync methods.  Note as I needed the `LocalStorageService` I also had to add my own constructor for the client in the partial class file, that made a call to the one that NSwag generates.

With this in place you can now, add a login page to call that earlier login method, store the token and now when you call the API and your Bearer token will be added.